# software for generating information from artificial/designed worlds with agents

Tags: data, modeling

Please recommend software for retrieving information about a world modeled with various parameters such as a number of [agents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agent-based_model), agent movements, time etc.

I seek feedback from folks experienced with any of these. There are many.

- NetLogoR
- AnyLogic PLE
- ABM Lab /Mike
- https://www.mdpi.com/2076-3417/13/1/13

  - ActressMAS
  - AgentPy
  - Agents.jl
  - Cormas (Common-Pool Resources and Multi-Agent Systems)
  - EcoLab
  - FLAME (FLexible Agent Modeling Environment)
  - GAMA (Gis & Agent-based Modelling Architecture)
  - JADE (Java Agent Development Framework)
  - JAS-mine (Java Agent-based Simulation library—Modelling In a Networked Environment)
  - krABMaga
  - MASON
  - MASS (Multi-Agent Spatial Simulation)
  - Mesa
  - NetLogo
  - Pandora
  - Repast (REcursive Porous Agent Simulation Toolkit)
  - RepastHPC
- https://dimensionless.in/introduction-to-agent-based-modelling/

  - AMP
  - Ascape
  - Breve
  - MetaABM
  - Player/Stage
  - PS-I
  - Repast
- gym/gymlibrary by openai --> gymnasium Farama Foundation
- google research agent-based epidemic